# Java Servlet pattern that starts with a string

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, url-pattern

I would like to create a servlet pattern that works for URLs like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/@77,aa,bb,cc
www.mywebsite.com/@82,zz,dd,cc
...
```

I mean, the symbol "@" and then, any string.

I tryied with:

```
@WebServlet(name = "myServlet", urlPatterns = {"/@*"})
```

...but it didn't work.

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change to this

```
www.mywebsite.com/@/77,aa,bb,cc

@WebServlet(name = "myServlet", urlPatterns = {"/@/*"})
```

Comment: Obvious, but that's not what I want